# Required network security group update - Port 5986

Tags: azure, networking

I've deployed a new AADDS in `Azure`. and ever since Im getting a warning on this domain service that it requires:

"Required network security group update
We have detected that your Network Security Group for `Azure` AD Domain Services does not include the Service Tag ‘AzureActiveDirectoryDomainServices’. We are in the process of making service-side changes which will result in a service disruption for you unless this Service Tag is present. To avoid this service disruption, the Service Tag needs to be added by January 18th, 2021. To make this change, follow the steps in this document: Network security groups and required ports. If you do not make the change, we will make the change for you starting January 22nd, 2021 so that your service will not be impacted.
More about service tags."

Now.. I have already added the required port the way they have explained in their article, but im still getting this warning everytime I check the "view health" in my AADDS.

Can anyone suggest a way forward to resolve this issue?
They said that they would automatically resolve the issue for me on the 22nd but nothing has happened

Comment: Perhaps, you can not add the NSG rules well as the required? Also, could you provide some links that you have referenced from it?

Comment: Here is the artcile
https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/active-directory-domain-services/network-considerations#network-security-groups-and-required-ports
and I followed the instructions exactly how they mentioned in the document,

Answer (score 0):

You may double-check if you have these NSG rules in the NSG associated with the virtual network subnet that your managed domain is deployed into.

Furthermore, you can verify if your configuration or function is working well excluding it's just a warning. Also, verify if there is any Azure policy in your subscription trigger that warning.

Answer (score 0):

So the solution was,

I had deployed the domain in a Resource Group called AADDSRG and the domain controller had its own NSG.

The server was in a separate Resource group and had its own NSG but it is part of the same V-Net as AADDS.

I had a chance to Microsoft representatives and they got me to add the Port to the second NSG.

I still do not understand why I had to do that, since they should only have access to the domain controller, and not the server that is connected to it.

But regardless, this fixed the issue.

Hope this information helps someone in future.